# Google scholar scraping with ip-rotator through AWS ApiGateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter, screen-scraping

I am receiving the error below. The code (George method, https://stackoverflow.com/users/7173479/george) worked in the beginning a couple of times and a bit later it crashed. It should be something with the configuration of HTTP but I am lost in the AWS documentation. I am working on the jupyter notebook. Anybody could help?

## Create gateway object and initialise in AWS

```
engine = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q={}&btnG='

gateway = ApiGateway(engine,\
                     access_key_id="KEY", access_key_secret="SECRET_KEY")
gateway.start()
```

## Assign gateway to session

```
session = requests.Session()
session.mount(engine, gateway)
```

## Send request (IP will be randomised)

```
header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) \
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}

search_string = '{}+and+{}+and+{}+and+{}'.format('term1','term2','term3','term4')

url = engine.format(search_string)
print(url)

response = session.get(url,headers=header)
tree = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
result = tree.find('div',id='gs_ab_md')

print(response.status_code)
print(result.text)
print(len(result.text))
number=[int(s.replace('.','').replace(',','')) for s in result.text.split() \
                if s.replace('.','').replace(',','').isdigit()]
```

## Delete gateways

```
gateway.shutdown()
```

=====================================

`BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `site` parameter for the `ApiGateway` constructor in the `requests-ip-rotator` package expects to be just the site.  It can't have any part of the URI other than the protocol, domain name or IP address, and port.

If you change your constructor to something like this:

```python
gateway = ApiGateway("https://scholar.google.com")
gateway.start()
```

It will construct the gateway endpoint correctly.